# Sample size for multiple hypothesis test: Wilcoxon test and Benjamini–Hochberg procedure

Tags: multiple-comparisons, sample-size, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, statistical-power

I have an experiment with a control and multiple treatments and want to find which one performs the best. I would use the Wilcoxon pairwise test to test all the hypotheses and correct the p-values with the Benjamini–Hochberg procedure.

In R I would use the following:

```
pairwise.wilcox.test(outcome_measure, group, p.adjust.method = "BH")
```

Now the question is how to determine the sample size in order to make sure that I can reach my desired control on the False Discovery Rate and power. It seems obvious that the sample size will go up as compared to just a simple hypothesis test, but I don't know where to start in approaching this.

It would be great to see an answer or source which really goes through the whole procedure in detail, so I could potentially generalize it to any test and any FDR control procedure.

Comment: Good question and no one answer. I hope we see answers in future.